# AND operator is not working in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

here is my sample mongoDB document

```
    _id    :ObjectId("58860899292cd2a5081f71d8")
  latitude :80.0596389601359
  longitude:17.1845395665099
        b4 : 0
        b8:0.0
```

when i fire this statement

```
    db.demo.find( { $and: [ { latitude: { $eq: 80.0596389601359 } }, { longitude: { $eq:17.1845395665099  } } ] } )
```

m getting zero records is fetched why ...can anybody help me

Comment: that query works for me

Comment: but m getting zero records is fetched  :(

Comment: Is the collection name correct? I've inserted your document in test collection and then used the provided query to fetch the document, everything worked as expected

Comment: yaaa its demo..

Comment: An *equality* query on floats is probably very error prone.

Comment: What do you get when you query with `db.demo.find({ latitude: 80.0596389601359, longitude: 17.1845395665099  })`?

Comment: @chridam  i have added screenshot

Comment: @deceze is there is any other way

Comment: same problem @chridam